# How to return the actual object from a mocked object with Moq

Tags: c#, moq

Let's say I have this method which has been mocked:

```
public Comfirmation AddCustomer(Customer customer)
{ 
   // add customer to the Database
   return confirmation;
}
```

And the my mock is like this:

```
_service
.Setup(x =>x.AddCustomer(It.IsAny<Customer>))
.Returns(new Confirmation());
```

How can I get the confirmation object / state from the actual method?
I know that the purpose of mocking is to isolate the external factors affecting the code behavior but I really need to get the computed result of the actual method. Because this result will be used in some other part of the test.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moq does not execute the `AddCustomer` function of the class. So therefore there is no way with your current `Moq` setup to get the `Confirmation` object, that the real implementation of `AddCustomer` might have been created.

If you need the `Confirmation` as input for another test, then it its the role of the **arrange** part of an test to create the input parameters for the method under test.

If you approach this problem by calling the `AddCustomer` function, then you create a **coupling** of the `Confirmation` creation code and the code that is using the Confirmation. If the creation code changes, tests might break in other areas and *it could be difficult and time consuming to debug the reason*.

For integration tests this coupling is the right choice, because you want to test this interaction of two parts of your software. For unit tests I recommend to decouple `AddCustomer` functionality from other parts.

Another approach is to create `Confirmation` objects that the `AddCustomer` function might have been created. This can be done manually or for more complex objects, by some capture/replay approach (e.g. serializing a suitable `Confirmation` object from the `AddCustomer` function  to XML or JSON and create the `Confirmation` object for the mock in other test by parsing the static XML or JSON string by a deserializer. E.g.

```
 string capturedJson = "...."; // <= JSON of a Confirmation object
 var confirmation = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Confirmation>(capturedJson);
 _service
    .Setup(x =>x.AddCustomer(It.IsAny<Customer>))
    .Returns(confirmation);

 target.SomeConfirmationObjectUsingFunction(_service);
```

Comment: Yes this is correct. Serializing the state of the objects would be the best way to go. Thats what you get when you try to unit test code that was written with no notion of unit testing.